# Real-valued function without complex variables

Tags: complex-numbers

Here is a complex function $f(s)$ of one variable:

$$f(s) := e^{2 \pi i/3} \left( \frac {i-s}{i+s} \right) ^{-1/3} - e^{\pi i/3} \left( \frac {i-s}{i+s} \right) ^{1/3}$$

When $s$ is a positive real number, $f(s)$ is a real number.

I only care about the value of $f(s)$ in this domain. **How can I obtain an expression using only real-valued algebra for $f(s)$ in this domain?**

Comment: Which third roots are you taking? Your expression isn't well-defined.

Comment: I am taking the canonical cube roots (consider the argument as a complex number in polar form, and divide the argument by three, and cube root the modulus.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is
$$f(s) = 2 \, \text{sin} \left( \frac \pi 6 - \frac 2 3 \text{arctan} \left( \frac 1 s \right) \right)$$

Comment: Could you explain how you did arrive to this interesting result ?

Comment: I drew out the Argand diagram to see what was happening geometrically to compute $f(s)$. From that, it's possible to use trigonometry to work out the answer.